Date timezone changes when manipulating date, making date math incorrect
When I create a new date, when I try modifying it to e.g. get a date 30 days ago, the timezone the date is represented in changes when I print it out, and the math ends up incorrect because of it.
In the example below it's initially printing in EDT and then changes to EST after using setDate. Not just that, but the math ends up being incorrect (off by one hour) since the time is the same but the timezones are different by an hour, and subtracting whole days should obviously result in the same time.
> d = new Date();
< Thu Apr 04 2024 17:14:02 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
> d.setDate(d.getDate() - 30)
< 1709676842549
> d
< Tue Mar 05 2024 17:14:02 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

I don't think you're doing anything wrong per se. The issue is that daylight savings time changed on March 10, so when you subtract 30 days from the current date the timezone is changing correctly, which is confusing at first glance.

That (the same clock time, 30 calendar days back) is what a lot of people would think of as “30 days ago”, though, so what your intent is becomes relevant to the question. Do you want exactly 30 × 24 hours ago? Date/time logic is some of the trickiest in programming, so explaining the context for this operation will help people give correct advice if you haven’t explicitly thought these things out (down to stuff like whether you care about leap seconds, even).

You wrote, "the math ends up incorrect because of it." Please clarify what math you're performing on the resulting date. You also wrote, "subtracting whole days should obviously result in the same time." Well, it does: the local time is the same before and after: 17:14:02.

@Fabio It's all correct though. Time zones change when you switch to/from daylight saving time. 30 days ago isn't the same as 3024 hours ago because a day doesn't always have 24 hours, it can also have 23 or 25 on DST switch days (and in some countries and during some times in the past we get even weirder durations like 26 or 23.5 hours in a day). It's the same kind of issue you would have with looking at year, which may have 365 or 366 days so one year also isn't equal to 36524 hours either. So you need to decide whether you want days or hours/minutes/seconds/ms.

(Fun fact: you can't even assume that a minute has 60 seconds because every few years it has 61, that's called a leap second. But in JS date calculation at least that doesn't matter because the milliseconds counter does not count the 61st second, it either pauses or repeats or the difference is gradually applies over a day, depending on the environment.)

What are you missing? That the timezone offset is always calculated with respect to the date you are looking at and not of the current date.
You seem to be in a timezone which distinguishes beetween daylight saving time and standard time. Ie during summer you have a different offset to UTC than during winter. And the date where this is changed is somewhere in between the 4th of March and the 4th of April. That's just how daylight saving time works.
So today (on the 4th of April) your timezone offset is UTC -4 hours. But on the 4th of March it was UTC -5 hours. So for any calculations with the time of the day on a certain date X, you always need to take into account what is the UTC offset for this specific date X is. You must not just use today's offset. It might work, but it might also be wrong.
Also for adding longer timespans to a specific date, you cannot just do something like
let d1 = new Date(2024, 2, 4).getTime();
let d2 = d1 + 86400 * 30 * 1000; //a day has 86400 seconds,

to add 30 days, because if there is a DST switch during that timespan, your calculations will be off by one hour ...
Actually in your shown example, when using setDate(...) the time of the day stays the same (ie 17:14) just the UTC offset changes. But 30 days in this case are not the same as 30x24 = 720 hours, but 719 or 721, depending on whether you switched from DST to standard time or vice versa.
I personally only seldomly work with the plain Date object in Javascript, because of these issues, but use some 3rd party libraries, which provide better methods for such date-calculations and dealing with different timezones.

The thing you put under “you cannot just do something like” is the other behavior that the OP seems to want.

@Ry-  Maybe, but that's not "adding 30 days"  because 30 days may not be exacly 720 hours. If one wants to do date calculation based on "days" they have to use "days" and not hours or any other time unit ... Or the other possibility is calulating strictly with UTC only. Then there is no DST or offset change and 30 days is always 720 hours

Okay, but if you want “adding 30 days” in the other sense using local time, d.setDate(d.getDate() + 30) intentionally already achieves that.

@Ry- Exactly, that's why I wrote, "you cannot add 30 days by adding 720 hours (or ~2.5 billion milliseconds)"  And as I read OP's question, the problems are coming from mixing datebased calculations (d.setDate(d.getDate() + 30)) and ms based calculations, because the latter will of course lead to unexpected result when passing a DST switch

Thanks, I assumed it'd always be in my current timezone, but it actually makes total sense. Never even came to mind that might be the case.
I'm gonna keep my current approach (setDate) so that I always have the same time of day as that's what's intended.

The issue is that daylight savings time changed on March 10, so when you subtract 30 days from the current date in your example (April 4) the timezone is changing correctly since on March 5 it was still EST.
